# Process Rails production and difference between dev and prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I finish a rails development and I would like to do the production on debian.
What is the process?
What is the difference between dev and prod? If I deploy my rails application development on debian, what kinds of problems that I encounter? (security? ...)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will face performance and stability issues.

One of the example:

In production mode, model are cached in memory, meaning that once they have been read once, the files don't have to be read again, bringing an obvious speed benefit.

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

Other Example:

The log files are not written for each line. It keeps it in a buffer and flushes it every 1000 lines to reduce number of disk access.

There are lot of other default configuration for production which are very essential for performance. So i would advise you to use production environment or create a custom environment by extending from production

Comment: Ok thanks, what is the process for production? passenger? capistrano? etc... A tutorial for production please ;)

Comment: Take a look at this https://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn/. But there are lot of materials out there depending on what you need

Comment: I try passenger but error:  undefined method `When' for main:Object (NoMethodError)